# Getting 'cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'redirectUri') error

Tags: angular, okta

I am trying to fetch details from okta and storing them in a Store. I have a `@effect` which will call a service file `a-service.ts`.

I am calling the okta library inside the service constructor like below

```js
@Injectable()
export class test{
  constructor (public a : oktaAuthService){
  }

  public getDetails(){console.log("metohod loading")}
  }
}
```

Getting error exception:

> unhandled promise rejection: cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading: 'redirectUri') ; zone:  ; Task; Promise.then; value;
> TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined... at new
> OktaAuthService (okta-angular.js:44)........

Comment: What version of Okta Angular are you using? I ask because `OktaAuthService` was removed in 4.x. https://github.com/okta/okta-angular/blob/master/MIGRATING.md#from-version-3x-to-4x

Comment: @okta/okta-angular:"3.2.2"
@okta/okta-auth-js:"^5.4.3"

Comment: It looks like you need to configure `OktaAuthModule` in your main `app.module.ts` https://github.com/okta/okta-angular#usage

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the above service but I think you might find something here

https://developer.okta.com/code/angular/okta_angular_auth_js/#create-an-authentication-service

Also can you share more details about oktaAuthService file to check as where exactly undefined value is there while reading the redirectUri.